# install Python module both as module and as script

Tags: python, installation, distutils

Say I wrote module `foo.py`.

I want the installation process to copy `foo.py` to `prefix/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` so that it can be imported by other modules, but also to create a symbolic link named `foo` (not `foo.py`) in `prefix/bin/` that points to `foo.py`.

How does one tell `distutils` to do that?

Comment: Generally, I would have the module provide a `main` function.  Then write a separate script which imports `foo` and calls main...

Comment: @mgilson This seems to be a question about how to instruct [distutils](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/) to set up the symlinks as described, not about how to write the code so that it may run as both a module and a script.

Comment: @qwrty -- Maybe.  But the way that I described is the typical (and most suppored?) way to accomplish this sort of thing with distutils as opposed to forcing those two things to be the same script which might be significantly harder.

Comment: @mgilson I use the `if __name__ == '__main__'` trick, which I thought was pretty typical.

Comment: if you want to limit yourself to `distutils` then I see all you need on a [single page in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) (`script`, `py_modules` options). You could also consider [`setuptools`' entry_points](https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools/pull/61#issuecomment-29262206) to generate scripts automatically (e.g. with a correct shebang)

Comment: @ErnestA: there is nothing wrong with it (`__main__` guard). It also allows to run the script as `python -mfoo` e.g., `python -mplatform`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian This document doesn't seem to explain how to create symbolic links.

Comment: you could create `foo` script as @mgilson suggested and point to it in the `scripts` option (`setup()`) or use `setuptools`' entry_points. It is not typical to have a bin/script that is a symlink to site-packages/module.py ([automated script](https://gist.github.com/zed/7865666) managed to find only one from ~400 python scripts on my system).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this if you use setuptools `entry_points`. Here's an example:

foo.py

```
def main():
    print "Hello world"
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="foo",
    version = "0.1",
    py_modules=['foo'],
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['foo = foo:main']
    }
)
```

Example usage, once the module has been installed using a tool like `pip`:

```
$ foo
Hello world
$ python -c 'import foo; foo.main()'
Hello world
```